# Accessing rendered HTML in Nuxt hook in order to process and change the order of meta tags in nuxt2

Tags: plugins, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I used the capo.js extension and my website has a critical ordering issue in metatags.
how can I find a way to reorder meta tags based on capo.js suggestions in nuxt2 SSR?

I tried to find a way to access `vue-meta` throw nuxt context , but I couldn't eny exposed api relate to `vue-meta` in nuxt context